# how to output only a specific known line number using cat or head/tail

Tags: cat, head

I know how to use `head` or `tail` to output a certain *number* of lines, but how do I output only a specific line number(s)?

Something like:

```bash
head --only-line=73 <file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I output only a specific line number?

```
head -n LINE_NUMBER file.txt | tail -n + LINE_NUMBER
```

where `LINE_NUMBER` is which line number you want to print.

You can also use:

```
awk '{if(NR==LINE_NUMBER) print $0}' file.txt
```

Or

```
sed -n LINE_NUMBERp file.txt
```

Source: [Write a bash script to print a particular line from a file - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-bash-script-print-particular-line-file/)

---

See Also:

- [An A-Z Index of the Linux command line - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/)
- [head Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/head.html)
- [tail Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/tail.html)
- [awk gawk Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/awk.html)
- [sed Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/sed.html)

Comment: I promise I did search!  Must have been a long day... thanks for the detail.  The `head .. | tail ..` does seem a bit memory intensive.  Perhaps on a fundamental level this is how any process can read the file.